# iPhone sdk how to handle orientation in UITableView CellforRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have UIImageView, UILabel which i created in UITableView CellforRowAtIndexPath, Since i need all those in each of my cell i added to my cell.contentview. But now am facing problem in handling orientation for landscape. Since i positioned the images and labels in CellforRowAtIndexPath am getting the same position(Portrait) when am rotating for Landscape too. My code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(680, 60, 40, 40)];
    [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];

      if([[[appDelegate selectDB] valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
      {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
      }
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{

      [self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

 if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
 {
      imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(890,0, 40, 40);
 }
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
 {
      imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(890,0, 40, 40);
 }
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
 {
      imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(690, 60, 40, 40);
 }
 else 
 {
      imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(690, 60, 40, 40);
 }
}
```

Also i tried this,

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =  [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,20,125,163)];
        imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(680, 60, 40, 40)];//self.view.bounds.size.width-
        [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];
        Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 60, 370, 28)];
        subtitleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,88 , 200, 23)];
        subtitleLabel1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(395,88 , 200, 23)];
    }
    else
    {
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,50,125,163)];
        imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(930, 60, 40, 40)];
        [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];
        Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 60, 370, 28)];
        subtitleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420,88 , 200, 23)];
        subtitleLabel1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(515,88 , 200, 23)];
    }
```

When i tried to use the above method, i am getting only Landscape positions even in portrait. What am doing wrong here? Can someone help me? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your code right (it seems a bit out of place, but I think I get the picture) you are trying to change the image location upon device rotation.  Your second set of code should work, in my opinion, but I have no idea where you put that section of code in your project.  It would only work if you have it in the right place.  I would do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =  [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,20,125,163)];
        imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(680, 60, 40, 40)];//self.view.bounds.size.width-
        [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];
        Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 60, 370, 28)];
        subtitleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300,88 , 200, 23)];
        subtitleLabel1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(395,88 , 200, 23)];
    }
    else
    {
        imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230,50,125,163)];
        imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(930, 60, 40, 40)];
        [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];
        Label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420, 60, 370, 28)];
        subtitleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(420,88 , 200, 23)];
        subtitleLabel1=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(515,88 , 200, 23)];
    }

      if([[[appDelegate selectDB] valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
      {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
      }
}
```

So you are handling the location of all the cell contents in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Now you would only have to have this code to tell your tableview what to do upon rotation:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    //self.tableView is the table containing your data
    //You can animate this with the duration passed as well.
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

The `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` call has limitations in IOS6.  Make sure it's actually being called when you rotate the device.